# install pillow==2.8.2 in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-imaging-library

I wanna install pillow==2.8.2 in python 3.8 with pip install pillow==2.8.2.
I see strange behavior!
It logs:

```
Collecting pillow==2.8.2
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-unpack-hfksy6uf
  Looking up "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/75/7667141ffeee4a38cf5f25857d3e5ae0d4b79d983a8c3c7af32c1a353848/Pillow-2.8.2.zip" in the cache
  No cache entry available
  Starting new HTTPS connection (1): files.pythonhosted.org:443
  https://files.pythonhosted.org:443 "GET /packages/36/75/7667141ffeee4a38cf5f25857d3e5ae0d4b79d983a8c3c7af32c1a353848/Pillow-2.8.2.zip HTTP/1.1" 200 9402887
  Downloading Pillow-2.8.2.zip (9.4 MB)
  Ignoring unknown cache-control directive: immutable
  Updating cache with response from "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/75/7667141ffeee4a38cf5f25857d3e5ae0d4b79d983a8c3c7af32c1a353848/Pillow-2.8.2.zip"
  Caching due to etag
  Added pillow==2.8.2 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/36/75/7667141ffeee4a38cf5f25857d3e5ae0d4b79d983a8c3c7af32c1a353848/Pillow-2.8.2.zip#sha256=57a900c2f30e53ed054adad401ab69643d9ab21e3acb0a647749a168e4e24446 to build tracker '/tmp/pip-req-tracker-mv517lx8'
    Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-install-eywc1p6d/pillow_db39585f6d9647fa9d6cb108bdb3df04/setup.py) egg_info for package pillow
    Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-8t24o43r
```

and doesn't continue anymore! It doesn't raise any errors.

Comment: try `python3 -m pip install  pillow==2.8.2`.

Comment: @AlbinPaul It doesn't change the behavior. :(